# how to identify whether the clipboard content changed from our app or from another app in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, clipboard, uwp-xaml

I want to do different action while the Clipboard Content is changed from our app or from another App.
Clipboard_ContentChanged event is fired whenever the Clipboard content is changed.If I copy some text from other app , i want to do some different action .how to do it ?
How to differentiate the clipboard content changed form our app or from another app in UWP ?

My Xaml :

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="CopyToClipBoard" Click="CopyToClipBoard_Click">Copy To ClipBoard</Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CopiedFrom"> Clipboard Content Changed From : </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="DispalyText" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

C# Code :

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Clipboard.ContentChanged += Clipboard_ContentChanged;
    }

    private async void Clipboard_ContentChanged(object sender, object e)
    {
        string str = "";
        if (/*ContentChanged fired due to clipboard content changed from our app*/)
        {
            str = "Text Copied from Our App";
            //Action - 1
        }
        else//ContentChanged fired due to clipboard content changed from outside app
        {
            str = "Text Copied from other app";
            //Action - 2
        }
        DispalyText.Text = str + await Clipboard.GetContent().GetTextAsync();
    }

    private void CopyToClipBoard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
        dataPackage.SetText("Hello Clipboard !!");
        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to differentiate the clipboard content changed form our app or from another app in UWP ?

Just talk from the UWP side, there is no UWP Api could achieve what you want. The [Clipboard.ContentChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.contentchanged?view=winrt-22621) tracks the changes of the data stored in the Clipboard from the system but it won't know the source of the clip data.